# npm run build fails within docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs

I have the following structure

```
- project
-- apps
--- microservice-one
---- Dockerfile
--- web-app
---- Dockerfile
-- package.json
-- docker-compose.yml
```

I'm trying to dockerize microservice-one but I'm unable to do so as I don't have a specific package.json for it.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  microservice-one:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./apps/microservice-one/Dockerfile
      target: production
    env_file:
      - ./.env.production
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
  web-app:
    build:
      context: ./apps/web-app
      target: runner
    env_file:
      - ./apps/web-app/.env
    depends_on:
      - keycloak
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
```

I'm running `npm run start microservice-one` within the project root in order to start the microservice but when I try to `docker-compose build`, it throws the following error:  `sh: rimraf: not found`

microservice-one Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:16-alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/apps/menzies-integration-service/main"]
```

I'm sure there are few things I'm doing it wrong but not sure what. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: if you do not have a package.json, how are you expecting to run your npm scripts?

Comment: it is using the main app `package.json` file

Comment: the easiest thing to do would be to create a specific package.json for your microservice and then run npm install and npm run build.